# Load Data Infile when adding new columns to a dataset

Tags: mysql, import

I have a table with the following columns, which has data already in each column:

A
B
C
D

Now, I have some new data I want to add, in some new columns that I already set up on the table:

E
F
G
H

The primary key is A. I made a new CSV file which includes the entire updated data set - including columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H. Then I used the 'load data infile' query to import all of the columns (A-H), to update the table and hopefully have E-H column values added to the existing data set, since the A value is already set for all the rows that are already in the database.

The problem is that when I do the import, it actually skips all of the records, rather than updating. Here is the query I use:

```
load data local infile 'C:/import.csv' INTO table import_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Maybe I need to use another function other than "load infile" when adding new data to existing rows? Why would it be skipping all of the rows?

If you have any advice, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `load` creates NEW records. It will not "merge" the loaded records with records that already exist in the DB. that's NOT its job. You'll have to `load` into a new temporary table, then merge the two tables.

Comment: thank you Marc. Is there a function for how to do the table merge? Is it always required to load into a new temporary table, and then merge? Or is there some easier way to update a table with new data, based on having the primary key for each row set?

Comment: if you awnt to merge, then yes. `load`'s job is to load new records into the db. for merging, you need to look at other options. e.g. load into temp table, then a `update` query with appropriate join options.

Comment: `INSERT` has an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause that can be used to merge, but there's nothing similar in `LOAD DATA INFILE`.